# Apply operation on columns of CSV file excluding headers and update results in last row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.6

I have a CSV file created like this:

```
keep_same;get_max;get_min;get_avg
1213;176;901;517
1213;198;009;219
1213;898;201;532
```

Now I want the fourth row to get appended to the existing CSV file as followings:

```
First column: Remains same: 1213
Second column: Get max value: 898
Third column: Get min value: 009
Fourth column: Get avg value: 422.6
```

So the final CSV file should be:

```
keep_same;get_max;get_min;get_avg
1213;176;901;517
1213;198;009;219
1213;898;201;532
1213;898;009;422.6
```

Please help me to achieve the same. It's not mandatory to use `Pandas`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you use the sep=';' parameter in read_csv() as the default one is ','? Can you write down your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you do not care about the index you can use `loc[-1]` to add the row:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', dtype={'get_min':'object'}) # read csv set dtype to object for leading 0 col
row = [df['keep_same'].values[0], df['get_max'].max(), df['get_min'].min(), df['get_avg'].mean()] # create new row
df.loc[-1] = row # add row to a new line
df['get_avg'] = df['get_avg'].round(1) # round to 1
df['get_avg'] = df['get_avg'].apply(lambda x: '%g'%(x)) # strip .0 from the other records
df.to_csv('file1.csv', index=False, sep=';') # to csv file
```

out:

```
keep_same;get_max;get_min;get_avg
1213;176;901;517
1213;198;009;219
1213;898;201;532
1213;898;009;422.7
```

Comment: If the values are large enough, ie. `661426176`. Those are getting converted to `6.61426e+08`. Otherwise, it's just perfect! :)

Comment: you can specify `float_format='%.1f'` in the `to_csv` method. Saves having to do the rounding step

Comment: @Foobar-naut that is just scientific notation

Answer (score 1):

`df.agg(...)` accepts a dict where the dict keys are the names of the columns and the values are strings that perform an aggregation that you want:

```
df_agg = df.agg({'keep_same': 'mode', 'get_max': 'max',
                 'get_min': 'min', 'get_avg': 'mean'})[df.columns]
```

Produces:

```
   keep_same  get_max  get_min     get_avg
0       1213      898        9  422.666667
```

Then you just append `df_agg` to `df`:

```
df = df.append(df_agg, ignore_index=False)
```

Result:

```
   keep_same  get_max  get_min     get_avg
0       1213      176      901  517.000000
1       1213      198        9  219.000000
2       1213      898      201  532.000000
0       1213      898        9  422.666667
```

Notice that the index of the appended row is `0`. You can pass `ignore_index=True` to append if you desire.

Also note that if you plan to do this append operation a lot, it will be very slow. Other approaches do exist in that case but for once-off or just a few times, append is OK.